# how to use placeholders in jinja2 template?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

i am creating a contact form in flask and i want to use html  placeholder's in jinja2, how to use html placeholder's within jinja 2 ?

```
<form action="{{ url_for('contact_page') }}" class="col-md-6 mx-auto my-auto mt-3" method="POST">

{{ form.hidden_tag() }}

<p class="text-left">{{ form.name.label() }}</p>
{{ form.name(class="form-control mb-2") }}

<p class="text-left">{{ form.email.label() }}</p>
{{ form.email(class="form-control mb-2") }}

<p class="text-left">{{ form.subject.label() }}</p>
{{ form.subject(class="form-control mb-2") }}

<p class="text-left">{{ form.message.label() }}</p>
{{ form.message(class="form-control mb-3") }}

<div class="form-group">
{{ form.submit(class="btn btn-primary btn-round mt-4 ") }}
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [WTForms documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html#wtforms.fields.Field) you can use `render_kw` to pass extra attributes to the widget. Something like this, in your form declaration:

```
email = StringField('email', render_kw={"placeholder": "you@example.com"})
```

Comment: no i am using flask

Comment: @vatsalay Sorry, I read a bit too quickly there. I'm guessing you're using `WTForms`, technically? I updated my answer.

Comment: render_kw worked ! I know that it's been three months since i asked this question but i have tried this today and it worked (: